# How to resolve flutter get pub issue in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have facing below error after executing 'flutter create sampleproject' in Visual Studio Code terminal

```
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust    
this source!
Got socket error trying to find package dwds at https://pub.flutter-io.cn.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Got socket error trying to find package completion at https://pub.flutter-io.cn.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
```

My machine is windows 10, and I downloaded flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable and installed flutter and dart extension in VS Code

After getting this error, I set user environment variable as:
PUB_HOSTED_URL -> https://pub.flutter-io.cn
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL -> https://storage.flutter-io.cn

Still I am getting the error, I also ran 'flutter Doctor' command in cmd and it is taking too much time to execute.

Comment: You should run the command `flutter doctor` just to see if your install is good

Comment: I also ran 'flutter Doctor' command in cmd and it is taking too much time to execute.